# How can I detect that a UIView subview has been added?

Tags: ios, uikit

I need to detect, from a sub-classed controller, when the root view adds a sub view (several levels down). I can find the subview by type once it is created (using a timer) but I would like to detect it when it is created. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can send a notification and observe for it:

When adding:

```
addSubview(customView)
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .init("ViewAdded"), object: timer)
```

On the controller (or anywhere else you like)

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(viewAdded), name: .init("ViewAdded"), object: nil)
}

@objc func viewAdded() {
    // Do The Action
}
```

Comment: I don’t own the parent view unfortunately, otherwise there would be many solutions. Any suggestion?

Comment: What about `didMoveToSuperView` method ?

Comment: Unfortunately this also won't work, as it needs to be overridden in the child view. Seems strange a controller doesn't get notified when a subview changes its subviews.